# How well can we approximate the Ito integral given a discrete sample of the driving Brownian motion?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

We work over the interval $[0, T]$.

Let $W$ be a standard Brownian motion, and $X$ an adapted almost surely Lipschitz continuous process with uniform Lipschitz constant $L$. Suppose also $X$ is uniformly bounded with constant $M$.

For each $n \geq 0$, denote by $\mathcal D_n$ the $n$-th step dyadic partition of $[0, T]$, that is:

$\mathcal D_n := \{\frac{kT}{2^n} \ | \ k = 0, 1, \dots, 2^n\}.$

Let $\mathcal G_n$ be the sigma algebra generated by $W_{t_n}$ for $t_n \in \mathcal D_n$. Denote also by $\sigma(X)$ the sigma algebra generated by $X_t$ for all $t \in[0, T]$.

**Question:**

Can we get an upper bound, in terms of $n, T, L, M$ for the quantity

$\mathbb E\left[\int_{0}^T \big | \mathbb E[\int_{0}^{t} X_s dW_s | \mathcal G_n \vee \sigma(X)] - \int_{0}^{t} X_s dW_s \big | dt \right]$?

*Note: The question above, to be more precise asks for the supremum of the given quantity over all $X$ obeying the given bounds.*

Comment: I guess you meant $\mathbb E[...|\mathcal G^n]$, but anyway $\mathcal G^n$ looses a lot of information about $\sigma$ (e.g. when $\sigma$ is independent of $W$). Is this really what you wanted?

Comment: Ah yes that’s correct. The idea is we only know the values of the Brownian motion at those times. I believe independence of Brownian increments reduces this to a question of $2^n$ independent approximation problems of time length $\frac{1}{2^n}$, but I might be missing some subtlety.

Comment: I suppose $\sigma$ independent of $W$ would be indeed the worst case.

Comment: Hm, maybe you are right that it would be a more interesting problem if I provided the full info of $\sigma$…

Comment: But then again $\sigma$ can well tell everything about $W$ if, say, $\sigma = W$. :-) Do you have a particular $\sigma$ in mind? (Edit: oh, $\sigma$ just turned into $X$.)

Comment: Oh, I would of course want worst case bounds, so something like the supremum over all $\sigma$ (now changed to $X$ in the edit). If that is too general/difficult, a bound for deterministic sigma would still be interesting.